# Fastreport font problem when publish asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, fastreport

I have a project which developed by asp.net core for backend & using react js for frontend.I am using fastreport for generating pdf.When i used fastreport design view my custom font works fine but when i publiished into server custom font doesn't appear. Please check below image link for better understand.I am using fastreport 2020.1 version & inside asp.net core used fastreport opensource dll.

1.https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG3Bt.png
2.https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY6gS.png

note:I am using **member code** for **agency fb** font.When publish agency font is changed.

Comment: i hava same problem. did u find answer ?

Comment: The problem is not solved.